How do I implement a zero (or negative)-timeout Gather to allow users to optionally respond to a Voice prompt followed by another Gather?
Imagine this desired behavior:
You call my Twilio number. A voice answers, saying "Press 9 for Spanish support. Otherwise, tell me what you want help with."
In order to parse a button-press I need to use a dtmf Gather expecting digit entry. But I also need to have a speech Gather (with auto timeout) initiated after the voice stops speaking so that if no button is pressed, the user can just dictate his query.
I wish I could do
<Gather input="dtmf" timeout="0"  finishOnKey="9" action="/switchlanguage" >
   <Play>
       [10 second track saying "Press 9 for Spanish support. Otherwise, tell me what you want help with."]
   </Play>
</Gather>
<Gather input="speech" timeout="auto" action="/maingather">
</Gather>

This way, if the user ignores the language prompt, he can immediately speak after the phone operator stops talking. If he presses 9, then the TwiML is interrupted by /switchlanguage, which will serve alternate commands (e.g. a <Gather action="/spanishgather">) in the case of a language switch. (Though I dislike that there could be side effects from the unprocessed second Gather.)
But this doesn't work, because timeouts have to be positive integers. If I set the timeout to 1 second, then since "when a  contains nested  or  verbs, the timeout begins either after the audio completes or when the caller presses their first key," if I speak right after the voice stops speaking, there will be about a second of audio that is ignored since Twilio will still be processing the first Gather.
How do I get around this?
